# Добавление, изменение и удаление глобальных данных в системе контроля версий Git

Tags: git

Как добавить, изменить или удалить глобальные данные (например, `user.name` или `user.email`) в системе контроля версий Git? Команда `--unget` почему то не работает.

Comment: Просто интересно, а откуда взялся `--unget`?

Comment: В хелпе к гиту в разделе действия (Action) есть такая команда  --unset               remove a variable: name [value-regex]. Подумал, что этой командой нужно пользоваться для удаления глобальных данных. Не вышло.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `git config`

```
git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Comment: Т.е. если я хочу удалить user.name, то должен использовать такую команду git config --global user.name " " (на месте имени оставить пробел)?

Comment: @ОлегКуксгаузен ну можно вот так например git config --global --unset-all user.name

Comment: @ОлегКуксгаузен а добавить git config --global --add user.name NAME

Comment: Оба (удаление и добавление) предложенных Вами способа работают. Спасибо. Нюанс, в команде на добавление user.name непосредственно имя нужно писать в скобках, т.е. вот так git config --global --add user.name "NAME". Предложенная Вами команда удаления user.name удаляет не только само имя (переменную), но и саму переменную. Командой git config --global user.name " " (на месте имени оставить пробел) можно удалить само имя, при этом переменная останется в глобальных данных. Ещё раз спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @ОлегКуксгаузен пожалуйста )